# Resources to learn APEX 1

Tags: apex

i am Fresher.im going to take training on SFDC in Bangalore.i dont know java.but i know c++.will you please help me whether learning SFDC is diffcult with out knowing java.please respond

Comment: no its not at all difficult .If you know any programming language sfdc is very easy

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing Java is not a huge barrier, any OO language experience is a plus, but just as @Mohith says, its not a pre-requisite.

I have added a few links below to try to help you get started

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_intro_learning_apex.htm

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4yX17_yxbI

http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-developer-tutorials/

**Highly reccomend walking through this book.  Hands on is far better than just reading, this will help greatly**

http://wiki.apexdevnet.com/page/Force_Platform_Fundamentals